# Securing Azure blob for only one user?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How do I secure a blob for only one user?

There are three options I can think of:

1) Shared access policy with a short expiry.
- The link to the blob is accessible from anywhere for that expiry duration, and for the duration of each subsequent page request.

2) Have a proxy between the user request and blob storage and apply authentication here.
- Though in reality there still is a publicly accessible blob for a short period of time.

3) We don't use blob storage for stuff that needs to be secured.

Am I missing a better option?

Comment: How will the user be accessing the file? ie. through your app? Directly through a storage explorer?

Comment: Currently through an MVC app

Answer (score 2):

- Your first suggestion of using a shared access policy with a
  short expiry is good
- You can also make the blob private, secure
  an MVC ActionResult and only pass the blob thru the action result
  (ie: return File())

Comment: but if I return a file from an action, isn't that downloading the blob from storage, then returning it? I.e. two separate http requests that could be slow, and point 2 in the question?

Comment: It would indeed be 2 separate requests.  However, the blob cloud be private and the access to ActionResult is in your control, you can check against users credentials and do whatever you need to stop the incorrect user from accessing the blob.  It is not a proxy as you would have to read the contents of the file and stream them out to action result.  Blob would always remain private in this case

Comment: Not the way I want to do it, but will probably have to go with this. - shame blob storage doesn't allow you to generate a Url that is only valid for one request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do as follows.

- time-dependent
- SaS using the url

```
    string storageConnectionString ="UseDevelopmentStorage=true";

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    BlobContainerPermissions blobPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

    blobPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(11),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |
        SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
   });

   blobPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off;
   container.SetPermissions(blobPermissions);

   string sasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(),   "mypolicy");
```

I suggest you to take a look at the article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj721951.aspx